# Trying to plot some sensor info from mysql to grafana

Tags: mysql, grafana

I just got into saving data from my electric meter using a software defined radio, I am trying to plot this info from a mysql table in grafana.

Here is some sample data and my query:

```
 <a href="http://i.imgur.com/pWRt5Ma.png">
  <img src="http://imgur.com/pWRt5Mal.png" />
 </a>
```

Create table statement:

```
  <a href="http://i.imgur.com/Duy8Iqn.png">
   <img src="http://imgur.com/Duy8Iqnl.png" />
  </a>
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to plot mConsumed to mTime for a single mId (%563) using grafana. Once I got this working I hope to get my gas meter plotting as well.

It seems no matter what I do it won't plot, and I'm really not understanding instructions on 
    http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/mysql/

My grafana query:

```
SELECT
   mTime as time_sec,
   mConsumed as value,
   'w' as metric
FROM UtilityMon.UtilityMeter
WHERE $__timeFilter(mTime)
AND mId like '%563'
ORDER BY mTime DESC;
```

If you know what I am doing wrong, please let me know, as I am losing my sanity by the minute. It did work with influxdb, but I'd rather use mysql since grafana can read it.

I had to codeblock my images... sorry not enough rep points...

edit- I figured it out!

```
SELECT
  mId as metric,
  mTime as time_sec,
  mConsumed as value
FROM UtilityMon.UtilityMeter
WHERE
  mId=xxxxxxxx
and
  $__unixEpochFilter(mTime)
;
```

Worked nicely

Comment: Edited question, I figured it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  mId as metric,
  mTime as time_sec,
  mConsumed as value
FROM UtilityMon.UtilityMeter
WHERE
  mId=xxxxyyyy
and
  $__unixEpochFilter(mTime)
;
```